# how to use zerotier in socket programming?

Tags: file, sockets, java-native-interface, sharing, zerotier

I am trying to create a file sharing application in which socket programming is done through c language and GUI is done using java. I am connecting c and java using JNI(java native interface).

Now to install this appication in different systems and establish communication between these application I was thinking of using zerotier, but I am not sure how to use zerotier to do this work of file sharing.

Answer (score 2):

ZeroTier provides a BSD-style socket layer via the SDK (libzt).

- Documentation / Examples: [docs.zerotier.com/sockets](https://docs.zerotier.com/sockets/tutorial.html)
- Github Repo: [zerotier/libzt](https://github.com/zerotier/libzt).

Basically you'd just build the library into your application and call the special ZT sockets in the same way you'd call normal sockets.